# Write Admin Messages in Bearle / Django-Private-Chat (Django 2/Python)

Tags: python, django

I was wondering, if it is possible to connect (as an admin) with a user and to write messages? I already modified the message-table in the database, however, the message does only appear after reloading the whole website - which is not the optimal outcome. I appreciate every hint. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use a pub/sub service to get notification on the client side when a message is sent in server side
A good start is [pusher.com](https://pusher.com) service, in your server side code, you will run this example code whenever you send a message to your user:

```
pusher.trigger('my-channel', 'my-event', {

  'message': 'hello world'

})
```

and in your client side, you add a code that listen to the above channel/topic and act accordingly

```
var channel = pusher.subscribe('my-channel');

channel.bind('my-event', function(data) {

  alert('Received my-event with message: ' + data.message);

});
```